# Android on screen number pad

Tags: android

I wanted to take Numeric input from user from Numberpad displayed on screen, it should be in Activity view. please see attached image.

I don't know if there is some way to make similar UI or do i have make one my self in XML ? . need your help. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indicate to the input method that you want numeric input:

```
EditText editText = ...;
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

and then most of the input methods will give you an arrangement like the one above.

You can probably get a view exactly like the one you show by sending an intent with an action of com.android.phone.action.TOUCH_DIALER, but getting a result back is likely to be somewhere between difficult and impossible.

You may want to take some inspiration from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/froyo/src/com/android/contacts/TwelveKeyDialer.java

Comment: @lain thanks for reply. the link to android source code seems useful.

Comment: I wold now prefer to write down my own layout for number pad.@lain  thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've updated the link, @Learner. Thanks for the heads-up! I'm not sure how useful it would be today, since it's to what is now a 5-year-old version of the code. I don't know where the analogous modern code is.